# Refresh stats in a simple time-counting program

Tags: python

I am creating a simple time-counting program for self-purposes. I am having troubles with refreshing stats, since I don't know how to get to the certain variables - they are out of scope.

When I try to run the program it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/str8/str8", line 67, in 
>      display()
>    File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/str8/str8", line 32, in display
>      + str(round(years, 2)),
>   NameError: name 'years' is not defined

Here is what I have done and everything appears to be right to me, except red squiggly lines under the variables years, weeks, days...

```
# str8.py
#   Program to count time from a certain event

from tkinter import *
from datetime import *

root = Tk()
root.title("STR8")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def calculate():
    event = datetime(2017, 3, 28, 16, 0, 0)
    tday = datetime.now()

    str8 = tday - event

    seconds = str8.total_seconds()
    minutes = str8.total_seconds() / 60
    hours = minutes / 60
    days = hours / 24
    weeks = days / 7
    years = weeks / 52

def display():

    thelabel = Label(root,
                     text = "You have been STR8 for:\n",
                     font = "Verdana 8 bold").grid(row=0, sticky=    W)

    labelYears = Label(root,
                       text = "Years: "
                       + str(round(years, 2)),
                       font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 1, sticky=W)

    labelWeeks = Label(root,
                       text = "Weeks: "
                       + str(round(weeks, 2)),
                       font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    labelDays = Label(root,
                      text = "Days: "
                      + str(round(days, 2)),
                      font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=3, sticky=W)

    labelHours = Label(root,
                       text = "Hours: "
                       + str(round(hours, 2)),
                       font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=4, sticky=W)

    labelMinutes = Label(root,
                         text = "Minutes: "
                         + str(round(minutes)),
                         font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=5, sticky=W)

    labelSeconds = Label(root,
                         text = "Seconds: "
                         + str(round(str8.total_seconds(), 2)),
                         font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=6, sticky=W)

    buttonRefresh = Button(root,
                           text =  "Refresh",
                           font = "Verdana 8",
                           height = 1,
                           width = 19,
                           command = refresh).grid(row=7)
calculate()
display()

def refresh():
    calculate()
    display()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: Please learn some Python before attempting to write code. This is a _very_ basic problem. Step through your code with a pen and some paper. Are the variables used in `calculate` visible to `display`?

Comment: Learn how functions are defined in Python and how to pass arguments to functions.

Comment: I know that @ForceBru, I don't know how to make them visible. I have some experience with C#, but I am a newbie in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return all these values from the calculate() function. you can do this:

```
from datetime import *
def calculate():
    event = datetime(2017, 3, 28, 16, 0, 0)

    tday = datetime.now()

    str8 = tday - event

    seconds = str8.total_seconds()

    minutes = str8.total_seconds() / 60

    hours = minutes / 60

    days = hours / 24

    weeks = days / 7

    years = weeks / 52

    return event, tday, str8, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years
```

Then call the functions as

```
e, t, s8, s, m, h, d, w, y = calculate()
```

Comment: Thanks. I posted the final solution

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:

```
# str8.py
#   Program to count time from a certain event
from tkinter import *
from datetime import *

root = Tk()
root.title("STR8")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def calculate():
    event = datetime(2017, 3, 28, 16, 0, 0)
    tday = datetime.now()

    str8 = tday - event

    seconds = str8.total_seconds()
    minutes = str8.total_seconds() / 60
    hours = minutes / 60
    days = hours / 24
    weeks = days / 7
    years = weeks / 52

    return event, tday, str8, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years

def refresh():
    calculate()
    display()

def display():
    event, tday, str8, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years = calculate()

    thelabel = Label(root,
                     text = "You have been STR8 for:\n",
                     font = "Verdana 8 bold").grid(row=0, sticky=W)

    labelYears = Label(root,
                       text = "Years: "
                       + str(round(years, 2)),
                       font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 1, sticky=W)

    labelWeeks = Label(root,
                       text = "Weeks: "
                       + str(round(weeks, 2)),
                       font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    labelDays = Label(root,
                      text = "Days: "
                      + str(round(days, 2)),
                      font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=3, sticky=W)

    labelHours = Label(root,
                       text = "Hours: "
                       + str(round(hours, 2)),
                       font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=4, sticky=W)

    labelMinutes = Label(root,
                         text = "Minutes: "
                         + str(round(minutes)),
                         font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=5, sticky=W)

    labelSeconds = Label(root,
                         text = "Seconds: "
                         + str(round(str8.total_seconds(), 2)),
                         font = "Verdana 8").grid(row=6, sticky=W)

    buttonRefresh = Button(root,
                        text =  "Refresh",
                        font = "Verdana 8",
                        height = 1,
                        width = 19,
                        command = refresh).grid(row=7)
calculate()
display()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

I did it like this and it worked fine for me:

```
def calculate():
    global event
    event = datetime(2017, 3, 28, 16, 0, 0)

    global tday
    tday = datetime.now()

    global str8
    str8 = tday - event

    global seconds
    seconds = str8.total_seconds()

    global minutes
    minutes = str8.total_seconds() / 60

    global hours
    hours = minutes / 60

    global days
    days = hours / 24

    global weeks
    weeks = days / 7

    global years
    years = weeks / 52
```

Comment: oh boy...don't do that. return the values you need from calculate()

Comment: I removed those global statements, and added to calculate(): "return seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years", but they are still inaccessible?

Comment: How are you calling the calculate function? can you show us that line?

Comment: just calculate()